# Windows Live Id OAuth with development environment in c#.net

Tags: windows, openid, oauth-2.0

I have just trying to make one sample application, by which I can login in to my website by Windows Live Id OAuth Protocol.

My application (Downloaded one sample available on net) is working fine. It opens the popup where i can supply my credential for windows live Id and then redirect back on the Redirection URL supplied in my account.

I noticed that when i supply live URL (lets say..... myappp.sample.com) it is redirect perfectly. But when i try to put (http://localhost:52254/WebSite9/default.aspx) this is not supported in my account.
(error -> You must enter a valid domain that begins with http:// or https:// - query strings are not allowed. Length is limited to 248 characters.)

My question is that, How can i use to test the whole thing in my local environment. Because it is not redirect back on localhost URL. Only redirection to Live URL.

Is there a way by which I can test the Live Id OAuth with development environment??

Comment: it is strange, no one has answer yet?

Answer (score 6):

East cake. Put in something like:

http://www.anydomain.com/ in the live app page.

Then add that domain to the host file of your machine (or intranet dns or whatever) pointing to 127.0.0.1.

The redirection is just a 302 redirect that happens in the browser.

Comment: +1 I usually create a separate app on live connect for local.anydomain.com and put 127.0.0.1 in anydomain.com DNS. That way every developer can test against live locally.